# Why INT_MAX and not UINT_MAX before switching to 64-bit ints?

Tags: c++, c, architecture

Why does everyone say that Google will have to shift from 32- to 64-bit architecture (with 8-byte `int`s) now that Gangnam Style has surpassed the INT_MAX limit? Why not use an unsigned `int` from the beginning, since it doesn't make sense to think about negative views for a counter?

Comment: It was [just a joke](http://www.avclub.com/article/youtube-was-just-kidding-about-gangnam-style-break-212669).

Comment: @HansPassant: Seriously? Nahhh, I don't buy it. Is there any document from Google itself about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's [style guide to C++](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html) encourages `int` over `unsigned`.

> You should not use the unsigned integer types such as uint32_t, unless there is a valid reason such as representing a bit pattern rather than a number, or you need defined overflow modulo 2^N. In particular, do not use unsigned types to say a number will never be negative. Instead, use assertions for this.

Thus does make sense, as there are far more videos with near 0 views than videos with near 2^31-1 views: it took years to reach the zone where `int32_t` behaves differently than a real integer, while every youtube post starts near the zone of the other case.

A failure in unsigned would (given exponential growth) not take that much longer either.  What worse is that if it interacts with 32 bit signed elsewhere in the codebase it will trigger undefined bejaviour pretty easily (overflow behaviour is undefined).

Comment: I wish the style guide gave at least a bit of the rationale for why a signed type should be used even if the value is never expected to be negative.  For example, one reason is that it it's pretty easy to have an expression that 'underflows' and instead of ending up with a negative number that's relatively easy to detect and handle as an error you end up with a huge value that's a bit more of a problem to detect.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the code is most likely written in Java, which does not have unsigned types.

Even if it is C or C++ however, some programmers avoid unsigned types for policy reasons such as the unexpected (to inexperienced programmers) results of comparisons between signed and unsigned types.

Further, just switching to an unsigned type would only push back the problem by a factor of two. It would arise again in the near future and require a second fix, and two fixes cost more than one from a developer-time perspective.

Comment: I thought of Java, but I decided keeping track of views would be part of the back-end, and thought it was surely written in C++. Right about changing now to UINT, I thought why was it not a matter of design. Thanks.

Comment: I was discussing this with someone else recently and was told that Google uses Java for most of their in-house back-end stuff. I don't know if it's true, but it seems plausible.

Comment: A third option is code internally using values of  -1 or such as "unknown".

Comment: @hvd: Yes, but in that case, `UINT_MAX` or similar would still be a workable sentinel value.

Comment: Yes, but it would not be obvious from the code: it could be a valid value. Signed types win on readability there, IMO.

Comment: @r.. Under what authority does your friend claim that knowledge?  I'm thinking about the good video codec coders I know (video is the core of youtube), and I'd suspect the contrary there.

Comment: @Yakk: Um, obviously video codecs are written in C (and asm); at least historically they were using libavcodec. That's a completely different component though. This counter is going to be in the catalog/database/website backend, not codec stuff.